# How to find out a specific string inside a jquery array object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a doubt in jQuery array object.
Let me describe briefly: I am having two arrays called `brandsLink` and`floorLink`.
when user will click any link, I am storing that particular brand name inside a variable called `brandName`, and the variable I am checking inside the second array. If it's found then I will write some other method. I am attaching a image for reference. I think it will help.
Here is the code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var brandsLink = $('.brandLinks li a[id]');
    var floorLink = $('#orionPlan .mapContainer area[id]');

    brandsLink.click(function(e){
        var brandName = this.id;

        if(brandName == floorLink.find(brandName)){
            console.log('yes both are matching.');
        }
        else {
            console.log('sory.');   
        }
    });
});
```

[image: reference image]

thanks,
naresh kumar

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use ID in this manner. An ID has to be unique in the document.
2. Your `find` call would search for `'someID'` when it should search for `'#someID'`
3. If you *did* find a match, you would be comparing `'someID'` to a DOM node

You would need to switch to using classes, or prefix your ID's to make them unique (eg. `floor-`, `brand-`). You would also need to change your comparison.

Given the following markup:

```
<ul class="brandLinks">
   <li><a id="brand-zara" data-name="zara">Zara</a></li>
   ...
</ul>

...

<map name="..." class="mapContainer">
   <area id="floor-zara" data-name="zara" shape="rect" coords="..." />
   ...
</map>
```

Your click handler could say:

```
brandsLink.click(function() {
    var name = $(this).data('name'); // name = "zara"
    var match = floorLink.find('#floor-' + name);
    if(match.length > 0) {
        console.log('a matching area was found in floorLink');
    } else {
        console.log('sorry.');
    }
});
```

Comment: first time i gave name attribute, i got same error. so lastly i changed to id attribute. then also i am not getting the correct match.

Comment: @user1614271: yes, well that's because that was just one of several things that was wrong about this code. I've updated with an example of what the working code might look like.